# How do I find the indexes in a numpy.array corresponding to results of its np.percentile?

Tags: python, numpy, indexing

I would like to calculate the np.percentile of a np.array and find their corresponding indexes in the np.array. Later I would like to use those indexes to get the values in a different but with the same shape np.array. Something like this:

```
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(1)

a = np.random.randint(10, size=(3,3))
b = np.random.randint(10, size=(3,3))
c = np.random.randint(10, size=(3,3))

l = np.random.randint(11,20, size=(3,3))
m = np.random.randint(11,20, size=(3,3))
n = np.random.randint(11,20, size=(3,3))

abc = np.dstack((a,b,c))
lmn = np.dstack((l,m,n))

abc
array([[[5, 9, 7],
    [8, 2, 9],
    [9, 4, 1]],

   [[5, 5, 7],
    [0, 2, 0],
    [0, 4, 6]],

   [[1, 2, 9],
    [7, 4, 9],
    [6, 7, 7]]])

lmn
array([[[17, 14, 11],
    [12, 17, 14],
    [11, 16, 13]],

   [[12, 12, 11],
    [19, 14, 15],
    [19, 15, 13]],

   [[14, 19, 18],
    [19, 12, 18],
    [18, 15, 19]]])

np.percentile(abc,50,axis=2)
array([[7., 8., 4.],
   [5., 0., 4.],
   [2., 7., 7.]])
```

I want to create a np.array using values from 'lmn' and index positions resulted form np.percentile(abc,50,axis=2).

Expected result like:

```
array([[11., 12., 16.],
   [12., 15., 15.],
   [19., 19., 15.]])
```

Comment: what if the percentile result for the 1st subarray is `[11., 12., 9.]`? How it should treat index `9` which occurs 3 times?

Comment: That's an interesting question and one that I don't have a clear answer. I believe the np.percentile is taking the value from the middle of an ordered array. So if I have a subarray like [5,5,7], I'd assume  it would take the value from index(1) since it is the middle index...

Comment: It's not about "middle" index, but about duplicate indices as they could be

Answer (score 0):

I found one solution:

```
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(1)

a = np.random.randint(10, size=(3, 3))
b = np.random.randint(10, size=(3, 3))
c = np.random.randint(10, size=(3, 3))

l = np.random.randint(11,20, size=(3, 3))
m = np.random.randint(11,20, size=(3, 3))
n = np.random.randint(11,20, size=(3, 3))

abc = np.dstack((a,b,c))
lmn = np.dstack((l,m,n))

al = np.rec.fromarrays([a, l])
bm = np.rec.fromarrays([b, m])
cn = np.rec.fromarrays([c, n])

albmcn = np.dstack((al,bm,cn))

arr_data = []

for i in range(0,a.shape[0]):
    for j in range(0,a.shape[1]):
        if albmcn['f1'][i][j][np.where(albmcn['f0'][i][j]==np.percentile(albmcn['f0'],50, axis=2)[i][j])].shape[0]==1:
            comp1 = albmcn['f1'][i][j][np.where(albmcn['f0'][i][j]==np.percentile(albmcn['f0'],50, axis=2)[i][j])][0]
        if albmcn['f1'][i][j][np.where(albmcn['f0'][i][j]==np.percentile(albmcn['f0'],50, axis=2)[i][j])].shape[0] % 2 == 0:
            comp1 = albmcn['f1'][i][j][np.where(albmcn['f0'][i][j]==np.percentile(albmcn['f0'],50, axis=2)[i][j])][int(albmcn['f1'][i][j][np.where(albmcn['f0'][i][j]==np.percentile(albmcn['f0'],50, axis=2)[i][j])].shape[0]/2-1)]
        else:
            comp1 = albmcn['f1'][i][j][np.where(albmcn['f0'][i][j]==np.percentile(albmcn['f0'],50, axis=2)[i][j])][int(np.floor(albmcn['f1'][i][j][np.where(albmcn['f0'][i][j]==np.percentile(albmcn['f0'],50, axis=2)[i][j])].shape[0]/2))]
        arr_data.append(comp1)

out_array = np.reshape(arr_data,(a.shape[0],a.shape[1]))

out_array
array([[11, 12, 16],
       [12, 19, 15],
       [19, 19, 15]])
```